# create a warped image with transparent border

Tags: opencv

I am trying to create a warped image where the border padding pixels are transparent. I know I can use the BORDER_CONSTANT = BORDER_TRANSPARENT. But this works by:

> In addition, it provides the method BORDER_TRANSPARENT . This means
>   that the corresponding pixels in the destination image will not be
>   modified at all. [openCV manual](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=border_transparent)

So to make border pixels transparent, do I need to start with a transparent image. Like this example:

```
int cols;       // filled
int rows;       // filled
Mat myImage;    // filled
Mat warpMatrix (3, 4, CV_32FC1); // filled

Mat myWarpedImage;
myWarpedImage.create((cols, rows, CV_8UC4, Scalar(0,0,0,0)); // set all pixels to black, alpha = 0

warpPerspective(myImage, myWarpedImage, warpMatrix, Size(cols, rows), WARP_INVERSE_MAP, BORDER_TRANSPARENT);
```

This doesn't seem to work. My warped image still has black background with no transparency (when I check it some photo editing software like GIMP).

Comment: How many channels myImage has?

Comment: 3 channels: HSV. Does myImage need to have an alpha channel too?

Answer (score 3):

... and the way to make the input image a four channel image is

```
cv::cvtColor(myImage, myImage, CV_BGR2BGRA);
```

Answer (score 0):

[warpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=border_transparent#void%20warpPerspective%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue%29) sets the destination image to have the same type as the source. You need myImage to be CV_8UC4 too. That's why myWarpedImage has only three channels after the operation.